# Download iPhone pics via shell (terminal)

Tags: iphone, terminal, photos, graphics, data-transfer

I've recently upgraded my iPhone from an SE to a SE2, and notice that the "Image Capture" app has trouble importing some of the photos. I've been holding off from using the "Photos" app as I keep all my photos on a separate drive (NAS) which is filed by Year/Month/Day since my first digicam in 1999 (a Kodak DC290).

For me, "Photos" does too much, I don't need all that functionality - so I've pulled all the photos from the Library in their UUID renamed state, ran an EXIF renamer over them, and have put them onto my NAS that way, however it made me wonder whether there is a way to simply do a "mv" in Terminal to remove the photos from the iPhone into my local DCIM folder (which has a script to then rsync to the NAS).

Anyone know a way to interrogate the iPhone from terminal? (Mac OS 11.0.1)

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Why not ask about the "has trouble importing some of the photos" aspect? Photos uses the same underlying structure as Image Capture, so the entire where you keep your pictures is really irrelevant to your issue. Image Capture can save to anywhere you tell it.

Comment: TBH I thought it was because Image Capture hasn't been updated for a while, and the HEIC/HEIF file formats were foreign to it ... but it did lead me down the path of wondering whether I could do this with a shell script, as my requirements are quite low (move images from location A to location B) ... happy to hear any suggestions regarding the core issue in Image Capture ...

Comment: Image Capture ought to be tied to the OS for versioning & ought to be capable of HEIC as soon as the OS was. I'm still on Mojave & never deal in HEIC, only RAW, TIFF, PSD, JPG etc so it's not something i've ever had to deal with. I do use it constantly, though, for my photography workflow, as like you I have no interest in using Photos.app for 'pro' work.

Comment: Image capture in version 8.0 (1106), is that a later version than yours? Photos is v6.0 (311.0.130). I've turned off the HEIC/HEIF format now (the iPhone is relatively new, this was my first import), so it may work on Image capture in the future, and this may be a moot post; however I was still curious to know if it could be done from the shell, as I use the EXIFTool to put them into the correct folders ... extracting them via shell could mean a one line command to go from phone, rename and rsync to backup all at once ... (theoretically)

Comment: My Image capture is the same - presumably no further improvements needed since Mojave. Photos is older, still v4. I'm afraid scripting is not really my forté. I tend to manually name each session folder & export my keepers to that, after they've been through Nikon's View-NXi, Photoshop etc. I cull heavily before filing - otherwise I'd have thousands more than I'll ever look at again.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about `Image Capture` - thanks for asking this question. I used to use it exclusively, but "lost touch" with it as I began using DSLRs. I'm sure there's a way to script this using [Automator](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/). Here's the [UG for Big Sur](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac)